# vr_ad performance enhancement mode

Tags: specman, e

I want to use the vr_ad performance enhancement mode, VR_AD_ON_DEMAND_STATIC_INFO. What do I have to change in my register model code? What if I use a register model that was developed elsewhere – and I cannot edit it?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a #define before loading vr_ad. 
If it is loaded:

define VR_AD_ON_DEMAND_STATIC_INFO;
    import vr_ad/e/vr_ad_top;